# Move each file into its parent directory in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find

### Question

Assuming I have

```
dir 1/dir 2/file 1
dir 3/dir 4/file 2
```

(spaces in directory and file names are intentional)

I want to end up with

```
dir 1/file 1
dir 3/file 2
```

### Related but incomplete answers

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/88202/how-do-i-move-files-and-directories-to-the-parent-folder-in-linux) moves all the files into the current parent directory (instead of each file's parent directory)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} .. \;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597433/find-files-and-print-only-their-parent-directories) prints out each parent directory but I'm not sure how to do the moving.

```
find . -name '.user.log' | xargs -I{} dirname {}
```

Comment: echo $( find . -name '.user.log' | xargs -I{} dirname {} )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find -type f -execdir mv "{}" ../ \;
```

The `-execdir` is like `-exec` but does its job in a directory where the particular file is, so the `../` part works as you need.

To get rid of empty `dir2` and `dir4` in your example you need another specialized command, but the main task is done.

Answer (score 0):

`for x in */* ; do [ -d $x ] && ( echo cd $x ; echo pwd ; echo mv * .. ; echo cd ../.. ) ; done`

Like what you see?  Then remove the word `echo` (from multiple locations)

Might not work in every case, e.g. if symbolic links are used.  Tested with OpenBSD ksh (preliminary results looked good on manual visual inspection -- I did not remove `echo` commands).

Note that `[` is a command ; it shares the same man page as `test` (although since it is an internal command for your shell, you'd want to use the man page for your shell and search for documentation on the command.)

Comment: shorter: `for x in * ; do mv "$x"/*/* "$x"/ ; done`

Comment: note you won't need the final `cd ../..` in your version; changing directory in a subshell (within the parentheses `( ... )`) won't change the working directory of the external shell.  (at least that's how it works in `bash`.)

Comment: I dont think this will work unless you first issue IFS=$'\n' or similar (because of the space delimiter)

Comment: @quixotic - yup.  I was pretty tired when I wrote that; I'm glad to see someone was able to improve on that.  I really don't feel like getting reputation benefit/credit from your excellence, though.  I'd rather see you post an answer and get well-deserved up-votes.

Comment: @davidgo it actually does work without `IFS` tweaking.  `for x in 'foo a' 'bar b' ... ` wouldn't.  i assume the globbing provides the magic.  @TOOGAM my answer got bogged down in explaining `IFS` and drowned.  hard pass.

Answer (score 0):

You're started correctly. However you can extend it a little in conjunction with the predicate `-type` to get just files. Using `xargs` and the bountiful powers of `bash` you have

`find . -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -type f |xargs -n1 bash -c 'cd $(dirname $0) ; mv $0 ..'`

`$0` is the positional argument passed to `bash` by xargs.
To watch it as it happens you can use the `-t` option to `xargs` as `-tn1`

Note: I've limited the depth of search by using `-mindepth $D` and `-maxdepth $D`, feel free to change as per your requirements.

Note 2: Kamil's answer (using `-execdir` is actually a much better solution).